# regular expression to represent time in a special format

Tags: regex, bash, search, grep

I have many files containing date extensions. For example, today's file would be named

> filename.20101118

and format is yyyymmdd.  I would like to list/grep/etc for all dated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean just something like this ?

```
/filename\.[12][90][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]/
```

Note that this matches non-valid dates, too.

or, more generalized:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[12][90][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]/
```

instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` you can use whatever characters your filename can contain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you're not looking to do any validation.

```
\.(\d{8})
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I have assumed that your "filename" will be only alphanumeric (ASCII).

---

My best friend [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)  says:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\.(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

**Matches**

```
filename123.20101118
FOOBAR123.19961212
```

**Does not match**

```
FOOBAR.88881201
foobar.20103512
filename.20101235
```

*Disclaimer:* I am just a happy user and have no affiliation to RB

---

**Explanation**

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\.(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])

Options: case insensitive

Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9]+?»
   Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(19|20)»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «19»
      Match the characters “19” literally «19»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «20»
      Match the characters “20” literally «20»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(0[1-9]|1[012])»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
      Match the character “0” literally «0»
      Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «1[012]»
      Match the character “1” literally «1»
      Match a single character present in the list “012” «[012]»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «0[1-9]»
      Match the character “0” literally «0»
      Match a single character in the range between “1” and “9” «[1-9]»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[12][0-9]»
      Match a single character present in the list “12” «[12]»
      Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
   Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «3[01]»
      Match the character “3” literally «3»
      Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest:

```
find -regex ".*/.*\.[0-9]+$"
```

Better:

```
find -regextype posix-basic -regex ".*/.*\.[0-9]\{8\}$"
```

Best?:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/.*\.[0-9]{4}([0][1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

The last one will find *any* year (we don't want a repeat of *Y2K*, now, do we?). and only months in the range 01-12 and days in the range 01-31. Of course, it doesn't validate for the correct number of days in a month or for leap days.